# Casting from const void to char?

Tags: objective-c, c, casting, void-pointers

Alright, I'm hashing an image. And as you all know, hashing an image takes *FOREVER*. So I'm taking 100 samples of the image, evenly spaced out. Here's the code.

```
#define NUM_HASH_SAMPLES 100

@implementation UIImage(Powow)

-(NSString *)md5Hash
{
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self);

    char *bytes = (char*)malloc(NUM_HASH_SAMPLES*sizeof(char));
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_HASH_SAMPLES; i++)
    {
        int index = i*data.length/NUM_HASH_SAMPLES;

        bytes[i] = (char)(data.bytes[index]); //Operand of type 'const void' where arithmetic or pointer type is required
    }

    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5( bytes, NUM_HASH_SAMPLES, result );
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
            result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3],
            result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
            result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
            result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
            ];
}
```

The error is on the commented line.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data.bytes` is a `void *`, so it makes no sense to dereference it (or even to perform the necessary pointer arithmetic on it).

So, if you meant to take a byte out of the data, then obtain a pointer to `const unsigned char` and dereference that:

```
const unsigned char *src = data.bytes;
/* ..then, in your loop.. */
bytes[i] = src[index];
```

Oh, and **[do not cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)!**

Comment: Thanks! However, I found that doing bytes[i] = &data.bytes[index] was a bit cleaner. And my computer science professor told me it was good practice to cast mallocs. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for NSData, `data.bytes` returns a type of `const void *`. Basically, you're trying to access a pointer to `void` which makes no sense since `void` doesn't have a size.

Cast it to a char pointer and dereference it.

`((const char *)data.bytes)[index]`

or

`*((const char *)data.bytes + index)`

Edit: What I'd normally do is assign the pointer to a known data type straight away and use that instead.

I.e.

```
const char *src = data.bytes;
bytes[i] = src[index];
```

Edit2: You might also want to leave the `const` qualifier in as suggested by H2CO3. That way you won't accidentally write to a location you're not supposed to.

Comment: Even better: `((const char *)data.bytes)[index]`; even slightly better: `((const unsigned char *)data.bytes)[index]` perfect: `const unsigned char *bytes = data.bytes; bytes[index];`